# Idiomatic way to prevent suppressing errors involuntarily

Tags: rust, error-handling

In most cases when we *intend* to write code like this:

```
let a = b()?;
```

but forget the `?` operator, the compiler will help us prevent a bug, just because the code that follows simply won't compile if `a` is `Result<T>` instead of the intended `T`. And that's great.

However, if we:

- call a "void" function,
- don't use the result of a function, or
- use the result in a way that compiles with both `T` and `Result<T>` (example: we just use the result `a` for something like `format!("{a:?}")`),

we might end up introducing a nasty bug, because an error might get suppressed instead of propagated up the call chain.

Is there any way to avoid such risks? A compiler setting, a function "annotation", or some other trick that could be used?

Comment: I don't know what case #1 means. Case #2 is already covered for `Result`s since they are annotated with [`#[must_use]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#the-must_use-attribute) (you get a compiler warning if it is unused and not explicitly discarded). And for case #3, there's only so much hand-holding that the compiler can do to prevent misuse, but you're starting to propose rejecting valid uses of `Result`s. Testing is usually the answer to ensure your code actually does what you want it to do.

Comment: For the specific example in #3, you can `#[deny(clippy::use_debug)]` to error on uses of debug formatting in your code. Can you think of another case where either a `T` or `Result<T>` would be accepted?

Comment: Thank you @kmdreko. Due to a too generic `#![allow(unused)]` I had missed those warnings from `#[must_use]`. For case #1 I meant a function returning something like `Result<()>` but that is actually handled by the `#[must_use]` so it's practically the same case as #2.

Comment: @PitaJ Sometimes I do want to debug-format a `Result` value, so I wouldn't want to treat that as a problem. Can't think of another example. As for case #3 I guess there isn't much that could be done - that's the price we need to pay when using type inference.

Comment: In cases where you do actually want it, you could `#[allow]` it locally.